# can't call javascript functions from console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I have the following javascript function:

```
function test() {
    console.log("called");
}
```

If I type `test();` in the console I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined(...)

Here's a JS Fiddle demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6w0w9sda/

Is it not possible to call user defined javascript functions from the console?

Comment: jsfiddle executes code in an iFrame

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do this in JSFiddle, which is "hiding" your javascript away from your console. It's not really in scope for you to execute. It's not working there like you are assuming it will...

If you created a simple HTML file and stuck your javascript in there between tags, you wouldn't have a problem running "test()" in console.

Create test.html and put this inside:

```js
function test() {
    console.log("called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not in the correct scope to see `test()`.

An easy way to get there is to add a breakpoint for the `load` event. Here's how:

In 'sources' there's a 'Watch' menu on the right. In the 'Watch' menu under 'Event Listener Breakpoints', expand the 'Load' category and tick the 'load' checkbox. Now click 'run' in JSFiddle.

The inspector will stop execution when the code from the Fiddle `load`s.

You'll see that JSFiddle has written your JavaScript as the body of the `window.onload` event handler, and that you can step through your code and execute your functions from the console. This is because your console will execute commands in the scope defined by the line of code highlighted in the Inspector.